# suddenly getting wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios4, keyboard, ios-simulator

I have an Xcode 4.2 project with ios5 targeting 4.3 and am now suddenly getting "wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003" error.
It occurs on the 4.3 Simulator (don't have a 4.3 device).  It does NOT occur on 5.0 simulator or device.

App runs as before and when the keyboard appears, all is good.  When I tap the keyboard.  I get the error.  Description is displayed once in the console.  Subsequent runs still crash app but error is not written to console! (So I'm assuming subsequent crashes are the same)  It's suddenly started occurring and I can't see anywhere the in the code, changes could affect it.

Has anyone else experienced this same issue and or managed to resolve it?
NB: I have already read the other posts regarding this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have now confirmed that it is not the code so my iOS Simulator must have been corrupted some how.